# What is difference between str.format_map(mapping) and str.format

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, string-formatting

I don't understand the `str.format_map(mapping)` method. I only know it is similar to `str.format(*args, **kwargs)` method and you can also pass a dictionary as an argument (please see my example). 
Example:

```
print ("Test: argument1={arg1} and argument2={arg2}".format_map({'arg1':"Hello",'arg2':123}))
```

Can someone explain to me the difference between `str.format_map(mapping)` and `str.format(*args, **kwargs)` methods and why do I need  the `str.format_map(mapping)`  method?

Comment: I didn't even know `str.format_map` existed ... Neat.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`str.format(**kwargs)` makes a new dictionary in the process of calling. `str.format_map(kwargs)` does not. In addition to being slightly faster, `str.format_map()` allows you to use a `dict` subclass (or other object that implements mapping) with special behavior, such as gracefully handling missing keys. This special behavior would be lost otherwise when the items were copied to a new dictionary.

See: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format_map

Comment: Strangely, a combination of changes involved in implementing `format_map` and edge cases in the `**kwargs` handling means that `str.format(**kwargs)` [actually *will* pass through `dict` subclasses with `__missing__` methods or overridden `__getitem__` behavior and use their behavior](http://ideone.com/Pwi54a). I believe this is the case on all Python versions that support `format_map`. It's an implementation detail you shouldn't rely on, though. Also, [only `format_map` supports non-dict-subclasses](http://ideone.com/TXjPyX).

Comment: On Python versions that predate `format_map`, [you can't abuse `format` this way](http://ideone.com/4xREdf).

Comment: In the time since I posted the above comments, [the `**kwargs` handling bug has been fixed](https://bugs.python.org/issue18531). A sufficiently up-to-date Python will once again not pass dict subclasses through in `str.format(**kwargs)`.

Comment: str.format(**kwargs) will throw an exception if kwargs contains keys the string isn't looking for, while str.format_map(kwargs) will just ignore them. IMO, this is another minor advantage of format_map().

Answer (score 7):

Here's another thing you can't do with `.format(**kwargs)`:

```py
>>> class UserMap:
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return input(f"Enter a {key}: ")

>>> mad_lib = "I like to {verb} {plural noun} and {plural noun}.".format_map(UserMap())
Enter a verb: smell
Enter a plural noun: oranges
Enter a plural noun: pythons
>>> mad_lib
'I like to smell oranges and pythons.'
```

Calling `.format(**UserMap())` wouldn't even work because in order to unpack the `**kwargs` into a dictionary, Python needs to know what all of the keys in the mapping are, which isn't even defined.

Another one:

```py
>>> class NumberSquarer:
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return str(int(key.lstrip('n'))**2)

    
>>> "{n17} is a big number, but {n20} is even bigger.".format_map(NumberSquarer())
'289 is a big number, but 400 is even bigger.'
```

It would be impossible to unpack `**NumberSquarer()` since it has infinitely many keys!

Answer (score 2):

`str.format(**mapping)` when called creates a new dictionary, whereas `str.format_map(mapping)` doesn't. The format_map(mapping) lets you pass missing keys. This is useful when working  *per se* with the dict subclass.

```
class Foo(dict): # inheriting the dict class
    def __missing__(self,key):
        return key
print('({x},{y})'.format_map(Foo(x='2')))  # missing key y 
print('({x},{y})'.format_map(Foo(y='3')))  # missing key x
```